# How to mutate the value in storage?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

```
let contract = Invoice {
                origin: from.clone(),
                to: to.clone(),
                amount,
                status: false,
                id: 0,
                msg: msg.clone(),
            };

            let mut invoice_vec: Vec<Invoice<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>> = Vec::new();
            invoice_vec.push(contract);


            // Save in storage the sender and the invoices
            <InvoiceSender<T>>::insert(from.clone(), &invoice_vec);
```

Above I do have a struct and I put it into an array and then I store it as a value.

It is very difficult for me to mutate the value in storage. Let's assume I would like to change the status from false to true if the id is equal to 17

```
if(id == 17){
<InvoiceSender<T>>::try_mutate(from.clone(), .....
}
```

Can you help me complete the above line of code?

Answer (score 1):

```
InvoiceSender::<T>::mutate(&from, |invoices| 
    invoices.iter_mut().filter(|i| i.id == 17).for_each(|i| {
        i.status = true;
    });
)
```

This should achieve what you want.

Comment: It does not work actually :/

Comment: Why? Is it not compiling or what is the error?

Comment: It does not store/mutate the new invoice.

Comment: What new invoice, you mean that `status = true` is not stored? Are you sure that you have matching ids?